# How can I construct a link on a web page thar opens HERE WeGo app on Android Phones?

Tags: here-api

I can see in my Android phone that HERE WeGo app open links starting with share.here.com and her.is [sic].

Problem is when I open a link that starts with share.here.com on the phone it gets redirected to mobile.here.com and opens the map in the browser (her.is does not open a map at all).

Is it somehow possible to open the map in the app from a html link?

Comment: @HARSHAsss thanks for taking your time, but I am talking about the stock app. The link provided seems for app developers. Maybe I taged the question wrong, didn't find anything better.

Comment: I think this is a generic Question and you should contact the support of here personnel on this one. nothing related to here-api !  @amundsmark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to trigger the HERE We Go app using Intents as described in this thread : [Launching a navigation app with destination pre-populated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56395840/launching-a-navigation-app-with-destination-pre-populated/59825251#59825251)

Comment: Thanks. Suggested solution opens app with a route from actual position to the cords in link. It is necessary to check user-agent for OS (which is ok for my use case).
Is there a way to open the app and just show the location with a pin (no route)?